# OAuth Verification using chrome.identity.getAuthToken

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-oauth

I have an extension that is working perfectly correctly using chrome.identity.getAuthToken (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-getAuthToken). I need to submit the oAuth consent screen for verification as it uses a restricted scope.

I received an email from the Google OAuth certification team about the creating a video showing the step by step of the auth procedure, all fine except for one step that states I need to show the:

> URL bar of the OAuth Consent Screen shows the Client ID containing the
>   project_number fully displayed (Note: this is not required for native
>   Android and iOS apps)

I am stuck here as the oAuth Indentiy API providor used by chrome.identity.getAuthToken shows the consent screen in a window without any URL bar! I can't see any options to change this or show it....

What should I do?

- Refactor the auth to a popup rather than using the
  chrome.identity.getAuthToken
- Try submitting without and see if it goes through?

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Received an email from who?

Comment: Sorry, received an email from the Google OAuth authentication team.

Comment: Is it possible to reply to the OAuth team's email asking about their review practices for the chrome extension consent flow? Specifically if the URL is necessary as the builtin `chrome.identity` API does not show this through the popup.

Comment: @jasonandmonte Yep I have replied to them, we'll see. Now that drive API scopes are included in the restricted scopes list, I am unsure of how a small developer can get through the oAuth verification, they are talking about a security audit that would cot 10K - 15K!  - https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

So, I replied to the OAuth verification team an explain that chrome.identity verification screen does not show the URL bar and received an acceptance less than 24 hours later.

My recommendation to anybody requesting verification and worried, is just go for it and explain where you cannot meet what they have asked.

Thanks